# How to check collision between two ImageView objects in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating a game in which I am checking for collisions between two `ImageView` objects, but when I use the intersects method it doesn't quite work the way I want it to. Score in `checkCollision()` method is counted to huge size and even though first image is not touching second collision is already happening and I don't know why - my program should add a +1 whenever one object touches another.

Here code sample after improvemets based on minimal reproducible example:

```
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.CubicCurveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestCollision extends Application {

    private Thread collisionThread;
    private Scene scene;
    private Pane pane;
    private ImageView  wolfIv;
    private ArrayList<ImageView> eggsList;
    private int score;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        pane = new Pane();
        scene = new Scene(pane,800, 600);

        Image wolf = new Image("/images/wolf.png");
        wolfIv = new ImageView(wolf);

        eggsList = new ArrayList<>();
        eggsList.add(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/egg.png"))));
        eggsList.get(0).setFitHeight(45);
        eggsList.get(0).setFitWidth(35);
        pane.getChildren().add(eggsList.get(0));
        MoveTo moveToEgg = new MoveTo();
        moveToEgg.setX(60.0f);
        moveToEgg.setY(95.0f);
        Path eggPath = new Path();
        eggPath.getElements().add(moveToEgg);
        eggPath.getElements().add(new CubicCurveTo(190,200,190, 200,190,480));

        PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
        pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(4000));
        pathTransition.setNode(eggsList.get(0));
        pathTransition.setPath(eggPath);
        pathTransition.setCycleCount(PathTransition.INDEFINITE);
        pathTransition.setAutoReverse(false);
        pathTransition.play();


        wolfIv.setFitWidth(200);
        wolfIv.setFitHeight(250);

        wolfIv.setX(140);
        wolfIv.setY(218);

        pane.getChildren().addAll(wolfIv);

        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        collisionCheckThread();

    }

    public void checkCollision(ImageView imageView, ImageView imageView2){
        if(imageView.getBoundsInParent().intersects(imageView2.getBoundsInParent())){
            score++;
            System.out.println(score);
            System.out.println("Boom");
        }
    }

    public void collisionCheckThread()
    {
        collisionThread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                while(scene.getWindow().isShowing() == true){
                    checkCollision(wolfIv,eggsList.get(0));
                }

            }
        };
        collisionThread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


}
```

Comment: The score is becoming huge because the background thread is checking for collisions repeatedly, as fast as it possibly can. So as soon as it detects a collision it is going to repeatedly add 1 to the score as fast and as often as possible until it fails to detect a collision. You probably need to check for collisions only when the objects move, and depending on what you're doing may need to add code to only detect each unique collision once. Using a background thread is almost certainly the wrong approach.

Comment: There isn't enough information in the question to know why it is detecting collisions when the images aren't really in contact. Create and post a [mre].

Comment: @James_D could you please verify now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the score "becomes huge" is that the background thread is repeatedly checking for collisions as fast and as often as it can. Any time it checks and the bounds intersect, it adds one to the score.

The reason you see incorrect results sometimes, such as a collision being detected immediately when none should happen, is more complex. This occurs because values (in particular the `boundsInParent` of the two image views) are being changed on one thread (the FX Application thread) and observed on another thread (your background thread) without proper synchronization. JavaFX, like most UI toolkits, is designed as a single-threaded toolkit, and so there is no way to add synchronization to this.

What actually happens here is due to something called "hoisting". The code in your background thread is essentially

```
public void run(){
    while(scene.getWindow().isShowing() == true){

        if(imageView.getBoundsInParent().intersects(imageView2.getBoundsInParent())){
            score++;
            System.out.println(score);
            System.out.println("Boom");
        }
    }
}
```

It is legal, per the Java Language Specification, for a JVM to optimize code in certain ways. For variables that are not declared `volatile`, and without synchronization, the JVM is allowed to reorder code assuming that each thread is independent of each other. Under this assumption, since there are no changes to the `boundsInParent` made in this thread, the code can be treated as being equivalent to

```
public void run(){
    if(imageView.getBoundsInParent().intersects(imageView2.getBoundsInParent())){
        while(scene.getWindow().isShowing() == true){

            score++;
            System.out.println(score);
            System.out.println("Boom");
        }
    }
}
```

Furthermore, this optimization may be made at an arbitrary time (when the JVM decides it may be beneficial), so if you are accessing the `boundsInParent` from a thread other than the FX Application Thread, the behavior of this code becomes essentially non-deterministic.

For more information, I recommend reading the relevant items in Joshua Bloch's book *Effective Java*. (No one who has spent more than an hour programming in Java should be without this book.)

Using a background thread here is completely the wrong approach anyway.

What you actually want to do, I assume, is add one to the score (and perhaps perform other actions) when the state of the images changes from "not intersecting" to "intersecting". You can do this by creating a `BooleanBinding` with the correct value, and which is bound to the two `boundsInParent` properties. Then register a listener with that binding and react when it changes from `false` to `true`:

```
    BooleanBinding collision = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
            () -> wolfIv.getBoundsInParent().intersects(eggsList.get(0).getBoundsInParent()), 
            wolfIv.boundsInParentProperty(), 
            eggsList.get(0).boundsInParentProperty()
    );
    
    collision.addListener((obs, wasCollision, isNowCollision) -> {
        if (isNowCollision) {
            score++;
            System.out.println(score);
            System.out.println("Boom");
        }
    });
```

Here's a complete runnable example which demonstrates this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.CubicCurveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TestCollision extends Application {

    private Scene scene;
    private Pane pane;
    private ImageView  wolfIv;
    private ArrayList<ImageView> eggsList;
    private int score;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        pane = new Pane();
        scene = new Scene(pane,800, 600);

        WritableImage wolf = new WritableImage(1, 1);
        wolf.getPixelWriter().setColor(0, 0, Color.RED);
        wolfIv = new ImageView(wolf);

        eggsList = new ArrayList<>();
        WritableImage egg = new WritableImage(1, 1);
        egg.getPixelWriter().setColor(0, 0, Color.YELLOW);
        eggsList.add(new ImageView(egg));
        
        
        BooleanBinding collision = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
                () -> wolfIv.getBoundsInParent().intersects(eggsList.get(0).getBoundsInParent()), 
                wolfIv.boundsInParentProperty(), 
                eggsList.get(0).boundsInParentProperty()
        );
        
        collision.addListener((obs, wasCollision, isNowCollision) -> {
            if (isNowCollision) {
                score++;
                System.out.println(score);
                System.out.println("Boom");
            }
        });
        
        
        eggsList.get(0).setFitHeight(45);
        eggsList.get(0).setFitWidth(35);
        pane.getChildren().add(eggsList.get(0));
        MoveTo moveToEgg = new MoveTo();
        moveToEgg.setX(60.0f);
        moveToEgg.setY(95.0f);
        Path eggPath = new Path();
        eggPath.getElements().add(moveToEgg);
        eggPath.getElements().add(new CubicCurveTo(190,200,190, 200,190,480));

        PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
        pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(4000));
        pathTransition.setNode(eggsList.get(0));
        pathTransition.setPath(eggPath);
        pathTransition.setCycleCount(PathTransition.INDEFINITE);
        pathTransition.setAutoReverse(false);
        pathTransition.play();


        wolfIv.setFitWidth(200);
        wolfIv.setFitHeight(250);

        wolfIv.setX(140);
        wolfIv.setY(218);


        
        pane.getChildren().addAll(wolfIv);

        
        
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


}
```

Comment: I have one more doubt. In the example you gave the collision occurs every time, but if I want to move one ImageView during the program, collision will continue to add points, what to do to collision take new points X and Y image ?

Comment: Sorry but one more question: I have a .png file but its borders are set by setX and setY and not by what borders it actually has, how to set the borders of this .png to check the actual file borders?

Comment: @matri1395 I don't understand the first comment. What do you mean by "collision will continue to add points"? (As a linguistic aside, please don't use the word "doubt" when you mean "question".)

Comment: For the second question, if parts of the image are actually transparent, you can try `imageView.setPickOnBounds(false)`. You may just need to code in the offset of the actual image, though, adjusting the bounds accordingly.

Comment: Ok but If the image has an irregular shape, how to mark the borders for collision? 
First question more easier:  For your example above, collision will occur every time because we defined x and y (setX, setY) but how to check collision if image is set: image.setVisible(false) (if the image is not visible the collision point should not be added). I ask because I have setOnKeyPressed set for keyboard buttons up, down, left, right and when I press a button I set image.setVisible(false) depending on the button

Comment: If the image has an irregular border, and `setPickOnBounds(false)` doesn't work, you'll just have to code around it (in the `collision` binding). One option would be to compute the rectangle representing the intersection. Get a `PixelReader` from each image, iterate over the pixels in the intersecting region, and only return `true` if there is a pixel which is not transparent in both images. For visibility, just include the `visibleProperty()` in the binding and check the image is visible as well as the bounds intersecting.

Comment: Sorry but it sounds for me to complicated. Do you have any example of this action with PixelReader ?

Comment: @matri1395 I don't know of any examples. Just read the Javadocs and code what I just described, it is not that complicated.